# Solving telegrapher's equation, using seperation of variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is question 4.2.9 from Introduction to Partial Differential Equations, by Peter J. Olver.

Let $a, c > 0$ be positive constants.

The telegrapher’s equation $u_{tt} + au_{t} = c^2 u_{xx}$ represents a damped version of the wave equation.

Consider the Dirichlet boundary value problem

$$u(t, 0) = u(t, 1) = 0,$$ on the interval $$0 ≤ x ≤ 1 ,$$

with initial conditions
$$
u(0, x) = f(x),\phantom{000} u_t(0, x) = 0 . 
$$

(a) Find all separable solutions to the telegrapher’s equation that satisfy the boundary conditions.

(b) Write down a series solution for the initial boundary value problem.

(c) Discuss the long term behavior of your solution.

(d) State a criterion that distinguishes over-damped from under-damped versions of the equation.

---

This question is assigned as part of a test review and not part of routine homework. The test review will not be turned in for credit.

I am having trouble understanding how to use the boundary conditions in this problem. I don't understand separation of variables because it seems like everyone that explains it skips so many steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of separation of variables is to *assume* that  your function $u(x,t)$ can be written as the product of two functions which each contain only one of the variables of $u$, i.e

$$u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$$

Substituting this ansatz into our PDE, we find

$$X T'' + a X T' = c^{2} X'' T$$

Notice that if we divide both sides by the product of functions, $c^{2} X(x) T(t)$, we get

$$\frac{1}{c^{2}} \bigg( \frac{T''}{T} + a \frac{T'}{T} \bigg) = \frac{X''}{X}$$

The key here is that *the only way that a function of $t$ and a function of $x$ can be equal is if they both equal a constant*, known as the **separation constant**, which I will denote by $- \lambda$. Hence, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{c^{2}} \bigg( \frac{T''}{T} + a \frac{T'}{T} \bigg) &= \frac{X''}{X} \\
&= - \lambda \\
\end{align}

which gives us two ODEs

$$\frac{1}{c^{2}} \bigg( \frac{T''}{T} + a \frac{T'}{T} \bigg) = - \lambda \implies T'' + aT' + \lambda c^{2} T = 0$$

and

$$\frac{X''}{X} = - \lambda \implies X'' + \lambda X = 0$$

So, in other words, we have *separated* our PDE into two ODEs. It then remains to solve both ODEs, using your boundary conditions. For instance, the BC

$$u(0, t) = 0 \implies X(0) T(t) = 0$$

which implies $X(0) = 0$ (why?) is a condition for your ODE in $x$. Try this for your other BC and see how you go, if you need more help just comment below.

Comment: The boundary conditions lead to the usual eigenvalues $\lambda = n^2 \pi^2$ for $n =1,2 \ldots$, but then the ODE for $T$ has solutions that depend on the value of $n$. That is, if $a^2 - 4n^2\pi^2c^2 > 0$ then the ODE for $T$ has two linearly independent purely exponential solutions, but if $a^2 - 4n^2\pi^2c^2 < 0$ then the $T$ ODE has two solutions involving sines and cosines. So any series solution to the original PDE must be broken up into a series with some terms valid for $a^2 - 4n^2\pi^2c^2 > 0$ and others for $a^2 - 4n^2\pi^2c^2 < 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I'd send kudos but my reputation is ruened!